# Prevent iframe from resizing when content changes

Tags: html, iframe, reload

I have an iframe inside of a table cell, roughly:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <iframe style=height:100%; width:100% src="content.aspx" />
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

When the page initially loads everything sizes correctly, the iframe expands to the full area of the cell. If you reload the content of the cell of perform a submit, the iframe collapses, presumably because it thinks there is no content, but then does not re-expand once the content does load.

Can this be prevented? iframe height = 100% always...

**Update: This is my actual iframe:

```
<iframe id="frmContent" runat="server" frameborder="0" src="Home.aspx" style="height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; display:block" >
```

I discovered the problem is the display: block, but if I don't use that the iframe renders extra space underneath it that ruins my layout causing an extra scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems:

- You must wrap attribute values in quotes when they contain spaces.
- The size of an iframe doesn't depend on its content.
- `height: 100%` only works in elements that can't increase parent's height, that is, those out of the normal flow of the document (absolute or fixed positioned), or those whose parent has a given height (not auto).

Comment: I forgot the quotes in the example but in my actual code the style section is wrapped (style=""). I thought that the size of an iframe would be static too, so why is it collapsing when I refresh its content? (This is IE11 by the way). I didn't understand your last point. Are you saying the height attribute doesn't work for iframes?

Comment: Here's the actual html

Comment: @Cef `height: 100%` doesn't work on elements that can increase parent's height. Because when changing the height of the element, parent's one is affected, then the element's one must be recalculated, and then the parent's one again, and it would be an infinite loop.